# combined bar, line, and point geom in ggplots2- how to change fill on point and dashed line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, linechart

Ive worked on this from a previous post: [Combined line & bar geoms: How to generate proper legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789458/combined-line-bar-geoms-how-to-generate-proper-legend) And have gotten close.  Here is the code I used which adds a line and point geom to the bar plot:

```
  mort12=data.frame(
     Adj.S=c(.68,.33,.66,.62,.6,.51,.6,.76,.51,.5),
     QTL=c(1:10),
     Cum.M=c(.312,.768,NA,.854,NA,.925,.954,NA,NA,.977)
)

  ggplot(data=mort12, aes(QTL)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = Adj.S, color = "Adj.S"), stat="identity", fill = "red") +
  geom_point(data=mort12[!is.na(mort12$Cum.M),], aes(y = Cum.M, group = 1,size=4, color =    "Cum.M"))+  
  geom_line(data=mort12[!is.na(mort12$Cum.M),],aes(y=Cum.M, linetype="dotted",group = 1))
```

(*Note, I have some missing data for Cum.M,  so to connect those points I added code to ignore the missing values*).

And when I run this, I get this figure (I cant post pictures here, so its linked): 
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B-6a5UsIa6UpZnRZTy1OZmxrY1E

Id like to control the appearance of the line and points.  But attempts to make the line dotted (linetype="dotted") did not change it, and when I attempt to change the fill of the dots (fill="white") I ge this error

> Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape

Any suggestions on how to alter the attributes of the line and points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
ggplot(data=mort12, aes(QTL)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = Adj.S, color = "Adj.S"), stat="identity", fill = "white") +
  geom_point(data=mort12[!is.na(mort12$Cum.M),], aes(y = Cum.M, group = 1,size=4, color =    "Cum.M"))+  
  geom_line(data=mort12[!is.na(mort12$Cum.M),],aes(y=Cum.M, group = 1), linetype="dotted")
```

[image]

All I did was move `linetype` outside of `aes`.  Generally speaking, `aesthetics` that are not driven by your data should not be inside `aes`.  For example, `size` should probably also not be in `aes`.